# Game Over Screen with Libgdx [Switching 2 screens]

Tags: libgdx

I have 2 implemented screen, MainScreen and OverScreen in create() of MainClass. In MainScreen I implemented game, in the end of game, I want to show OverScreen, in OverScreen, user clicks into it, and it brings MainScreen back. How to switch 2 screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your GameClass object to your current screen in the constructor and then in your touchDown() method of your InputProcessor you can call gameClass.setScreen();

Lets suppose GameClass is the name of your class that extends Game. Then the constructor of your MainScreen would look like this:

```
GameClass game;
public class MainScreen(GameClass game){
       this.game = game;
}
```

In your game class, you will pass "this" as argument.

```
setScreen(new MainScreen(this));
```

Now you can call this anywhere to change screen:

```
game.setScreen(new OverScreen());
```